# My system stops when including/using scanf

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, scanf, bare-metal, newlib

I have been working on a "os" (is not really an os yet) for my Raspberry Pi B+ and when I was working with the input of data I could not get scanf() to work, every time I include it into my os, my os does not even start. I have searched for lots of websites, but it seems like it is a bug that I made (very likely), and I don't know how to find it, so I ask you all for help. I will provide all the code that is needed so if you need anything else just tell me.

My input functions:

```
int _read(int file, char *buf, int len) {
    volatile int i;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        buf[i] = RPI_GetChar();
        if(buf[i] == '\n')
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return i;
}

char RPI_GetChar(void)
{
    unsigned char in;
    unsigned char pot = 0;
    char out = 0;
    unsigned char confirm = false;
    unsigned char shift = false;
    while(!confirm)
    {
        in = RPI_UartRead();
        if(in & 0x80)
        {
            pot = in & 0x0F;
        }
        else
        {
            switch(in)
            {
            case 0:
                break;
            case 1:
                //Enter - Space
                if(shift)
                    return ' ';
                else{
                    return '\n';
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                //Shift - Select key
                if(shift)
                    confirm = true;
                else
                    shift = true;
                break;
            case 3:
                out = 97;
                break;
            case 4:
                out = 107;
                break;
            case 5:
                out = 117;
                break;
            case 6:
                if(shift)
                    out = 33;
                else
                    out = 48;
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            }
        }
        sendChar(out+pot);
        mvCursor(getx()-1, gety());
    }
    mvCursor(getx()+1, gety());
    return out+pot;
}
```

My Cflags: -O1 -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=hard -march=armv6zk -mtune=arm1176jzf-s -nostartfiles -Wall

I already solved the problem with enabling the VFP for the printf() so it should't be a problem.

```
int kernel_main()
{
    initLCD();
    RPI_UartInit();
    char i = 'a';

    printf("Hi?\n");
    // Always when I add scanf to my code, my os does not start
    scanf("%c", &i); 
    printf("Hi %c\n", i);
    while(1);
}
```

I have tested the same code but with getchar() instead of scanf(), and it worked perfectly. And the RPI_GetChar() works without any problems by itself.

Thanks for your help.
(By doesn't even start I meant my operative system didn't even start at all, just like if the kernel_main function was empty)

Comment: Your problem description is hard to understand. What do you mean by "doesn't even start"? What happens or doesn't happen exactly?

Comment: Try renaming your `_read` function to something like `my_read`

Comment: David, By doesn't even start I meant my operative system didn't even start at all, just like if the kernel_main function was empty

Comment: so you are making your own operating system?  and using printf and scanf which are massively complicated, definitely require C library support and possibly operating system support, so it is back on you, what is your kernel support for this.  what C library are you using, and how have you interfaced that to your kernel/os?  start there.

Comment: this is elementary operating system stuff, including disassembling what the compiler has produced, and/or understanding the library and its backend.  Are you sure you are ready to write an operating system?   What did the compiler produce, where does it interface with your os, and how are you debugging those interfaces that are different from the prior ones you have dealt with with printf and other high level functions?

Comment: Well, thanks a lot, i actually stopped using the newlib, and started creating my kernel freestanding, so this shouldn't be a problem anymore. But i'll try to follow your tips.